# Issue with lookup('dig') not finding 'dnspython'

Tags: python, ansible, lookup

On a Red Hat 8.3 machine I try to use this ansible code:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('dig', 'localhost') }}"
```

But I get an error:

```json
TASK*****************************************
fatal: [demo.example.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dig'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: The dig lookup requires the python 'dnspython' library and it is not installed"}
```

I think maybe the `lookup('dig')` doesn't search in the right place...

However I think I do in fact have `dnspython` installed:

```bash
pip3 install dnspython --user
Requirement already satisfied: dnspython in /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

More info:

```bash
ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.7]
python version = 3.8.3
```

Comment: When you use the `pip3` command it references the Python 3.6 version you have installed: `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` as you can see it says python3.6 and not 3.8. To install the module in 3.8, try to use `pip3.8` instead.

Comment: This is it! Thank you :D
I didn't pay enough attention to the pyhton version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

When you use the `pip3` command it references the Python 3.6 version you have installed: `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` as you can see it says python3.6 and not 3.8. To install the module in 3.8, try to use `pip3.8` instead.